# improve my binary search program to a recursive one?

Tags: c++, c, search, recursion

I'm writing a recursive binary search program. Here's what I've got so far. The parameters of this program are that it contains 2 functions, the main function, and the second function, which will preform the binary sort on the values that it's passed. The program works, but it doesn't search the function recursively and I don't think it uses binary search...

```
/* ex06_18.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 10

/* function prototype */
void someFunction( const int b[], int startIndex, int size );

/* function main begins program execution */
int main( void )
{
int a[ SIZE ] = { 8, 3, 1, 2, 6, 0, 9, 7, 4, 5 }; /* initialize a */
printf( "Answer is:\n" );
someFunction( a, 0, SIZE );
 printf( "\n" );
return 0; /* indicates successful termination */
}
void someFunction( const int b[], int startIndex, int size )
{
if ( startIndex < size ) {
someFunction( b, startIndex + 1, size );
printf( "%d ", b[ startIndex ] );
} /* end if */
} /* end function someFunction */
```

Comment: "The program works" -- Not unless you have a radically different notion of "search" than everyone else. " it doesn't search the function recursively" -- only because it doesn't search; it is recursive, obviously. "I don't think it uses binary search" -- you don't think? Did you skip the discussion in class and fail to read the textbook on that subject? Even if so, there's a googol of references available via google. "the binary sort" -- wait, now you want to sort? sort, search, and just printing out all the values are three different things.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is just printing the array backwards, isn't it? You can read up the binary search algorithm in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm. I don't see any reason why you say that it "must" be a recursive function. I would prefer a non-recursive function of a binary search, even though in the wikipedia link it also has the recursive approach.

Answer (score 0):

Binary search only works if your dataset is sorted; otherwise less-than and greater-than comparisons are completely useless because they don't tell you anything about where any other element is. So first you need to ensure that your dataset is sorted - that's a separate problem.

Once you have a sorted dataset, you're trying to come up with a function that follows this general form (pseudocode, not actual C++):

```
function search(needle, haystack, start, end) {
    int middle_idx = haystack[(start+end)/2]
    if(haystack[middle_idx] == needle)
        return middle_idx;
    else if(haystack[middle_idx] < needle)
        return search(needle, haystack, start, middle_idx-1)
    else if(haystack[middle_idx] > needle)
        return search(needle, haystack, middle_idx+1, end)
```

Make sure you deal with any edge cases that pop up. In particular, think about what happens if the needle is nowhere to be found in the haystack; can you add something that deals with this case?